# Gitlab CI/CD hangs when committing changes

Tags: node.js, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Good Evening,
I am trying to implement Gitlab CI/CD using the Angular ng test command. The pipeline runs,

but hangs. I know Karma uses chrome. I am not sure what to add. Any help is appreciated thank you.

```js
image: node:latest

before_script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
    - gem install dpl
    - npm link @angular/cli

stages:
    - test
    - production

unit-test:
    stage: test
    image: trion/ng-cli-karma:${CLI_VERSION}
    script:
        - npm install 
        - ng test
    only:
        - master

production:
    type: deploy
    stage: production
    image: ruby:latest
    script:
        - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_APP_PRODUCTION --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
    only:
        - master
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the tests run and then the pipeline hangs? If that is the case, I bet it is because `ng test` runs in watch mode and is always running looking for changes.

To fix it, change `ng test` to `ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless`.

I changed the browser to be headless Chrome as well (optional) and this should bring a slight increase in speed in your CI/CD

The flags can be found [here](https://angular.io/cli/test).

Comment: Thats exactly what happens, I will add those flags.